# How to solve this JQ string concatenation issue?

Tags: json, jq

I am making an API call, and it returns me a json body. After that, I want to extract some value per each result entry.

Here the picture of my full API response body:

```
{
  "count": 7,
  "results": [
    {
      "index": 1,
      "response": {
        "error": "Restore full config failed Case1."
      },
      "status_code": 500,
      "msg": "[Fullconfig:POST:blalblablabla:admin] Status code: 500",
      "sort": [
        1562572224627
      ]
    },
    {
      "index": 2,
      "response": {
        "error": "Restore full config failed Case2."
      },
      "status_code": 500,
      "msg": "[Fullconfig:POST:blalblabla:admin] Status code: 500",
      "sort": [
        1562572216215
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have added this extra jq command after my api call:

```
< my api call here >  | jq  '.results[].response.error + " ==> " + .results[].msg'
```

And I have got 4 rows, instead of 2.

```
"Restore full config failed Case1. ==> [Fullconfig:POST:blalblablabla:admin] Status code: 500"
"Restore full config failed Case2. ==> [Fullconfig:POST:blalblablabla:admin] Status code: 500"
"Restore full config failed Case1. ==> [Fullconfig:POST:blalblabla:admin] Status code: 500"
"Restore full config failed Case2. ==> [Fullconfig:POST:blalblabla:admin] Status code: 500"
```

How do I correct that ?

Thanks,

Jack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are iterating independently by using results twice, so you get every combination of the errors and messages, instead you want to pipe results elements in as the input to use each result alone:

```
.. | jq  '.results[] | .response.error + " ==> " + .msg'
```

Comment: very nice. Thank you for the tips.